# Whem might "Mask R-CNN" come to CNTK?

Tags: cntk

The very recent paper on "Mask R-CNN" is really interesting.  Is there somebody in the CNTK community who might implement it in CNTK and share?

Answer (score 0):

We are not aware of a CNTK implementation. We will add this to our backlog. We always welcome community contributions.